# How to find out the email host of a vanity email address?

Tags: email, server, dns-domain

Assuming a person gets his own domain address, say, theperson.com.

He then goes on to create a vanity email address with that domain. e.g. me@theperson.com.

me@theperson.com may be hosted by the person's own mail server, or somewhere else that offers vanity email services, such as Gmail, Yahoo mail etc.

To the uninitiated, using a commercial email service is useful as the service is already set up and running, and provides a more secure and stable environment compared to setting up a personal mail server from scratch.

So for an outsider, how do we find out which email service a person is using? Can I find out that me@theperson.com is actually hosted by Yahoo, or some other service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [one of the online MX (Mail Exchanger) record lookup tools](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=online%20MX%20record%20lookup), for example [MX Lookup](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx:stackexchange.com&run=toolpage#) on MX Toolbox. On Linux, you could also run `dig stackexchange.com mx`. Obviously, you'd replace `stackexchange.com` with whichever domain name you're interested in. On Windows, follow [instructions from @Stephane](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/52287/20074) for the command prompt syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [MX DNS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) associated with the domain name.

e.g (under Windows, for @stackexchange.com):

```
O:\>nslookup
Default Server:  **********
Address:  **********

> set type=mx
> stackexchange.com
Server:  **********
Address:  **********

Non-authoritative answer:
stackexchange.com       MX preference = 1, mail exchanger = aspmx.l.google.com
stackexchange.com       MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
stackexchange.com       MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
stackexchange.com       MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = aspmx2.googlemail.com
stackexchange.com       MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = aspmx3.googlemail.com

aspmx.l.google.com      internet address = 74.125.136.27
aspmx.l.google.com      AAAA IPv6 address = 2a00:1450:4013:c01::1a
alt1.aspmx.l.google.com internet address = 74.125.143.27
alt1.aspmx.l.google.com AAAA IPv6 address = 2a00:1450:4010:c03::1a
alt2.aspmx.l.google.com internet address = 74.125.25.27
alt2.aspmx.l.google.com AAAA IPv6 address = 2607:f8b0:400e:c03::1b
aspmx2.googlemail.com   internet address = 74.125.143.27
aspmx2.googlemail.com   AAAA IPv6 address = 2a00:1450:4010:c03::1b
aspmx3.googlemail.com   internet address = 74.125.25.27
aspmx3.googlemail.com   AAAA IPv6 address = 2607:f8b0:400e:c03::1b
>
```

-> Google